# Como usar a classe InCallService no Android Studio

Tags: android

A minha duvida é a seguinte, quero fazer meu próprio aplicativo para efetuar uma chamada telefônica, mas não quero utilizar a view padrão do android, quero construir minha apropria View, mas esto tendo problema em acessar a classe InCallService, pois não esta disponível através do pacote "android.telecom.InCallService".

Alguém ja teve o mesmo problema ?

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeDorazzi, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Você poderia adicionar mais algumas informações sobre o seu problema? Que tipo de mensagem aparece quando você tenta usar a classe? O que você tentou fazer até agora para solucionar o problema? Essas informações são importantes e ajudam a comunidade a solucionar o seu problema de maneira mais rápida e precisa :)

Comment: Você pode editar a sua pergunta adicionando a lista de **imports** que fica no cabeçalho da classe na qual você está querendo usar o **InCallService** e também o **build.gradle(app)** ?